# Add Column with Default value from existing JSON Column

Tags: mysql, sql, json, string, alter-table

I have a table with name **GDN_AUDIT_TRAIL** having JSON column with name

**DETAILS**.

I want to add new column SOLUTION_ID in this table, so that the default value of this column should be one of the field from DETAILS JSON Column.
I have tried below query which is giving error -

```
ALTER TABLE GDN_AUDIT_TRAIL 
ADD COLUMN SOLUTION_ID VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(DETAILS,'$.SolutionID')) AFTER ACTION_TYPE;
```

Please let me know if this is possible.

Comment: Specify precise MySQL version. Show exact `GDN_AUDIT_TRAIL`'s `CREATE TABLE` script.

Comment: Please also include the error you received. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to surround the expression given as a default with parentheses for MySQL to properly understand it:

```
alter table gdn_audit_trail 
    add column solution_id varchar(50) 
    default (json_unquote(json_extract(details,'$.SolutionID'))) after action_type; 
         -- ^ --                                            -- ^ --
```

Note that using expresions in the `DEFAULT` clause requires MySQL 8.0.13. In earlier versions, only literal constants were allowed (with `current_timestamp` being the only exceptions). This is [well explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> **Handling of Explicit Defaults as of MySQL 8.0.13**
>
> The default value specified in a `DEFAULT` clause can be a literal constant or an expression. With one exception, enclose expression default values within parentheses to distinguish them from literal constant default values.
>
> [...]
>
> **Handling of Explicit Defaults Prior to MySQL 8.0.13**
>
> With one exception, the default value specified in a `DEFAULT` clause must be a literal constant; it cannot be a function or an expression.